# Java ME SDK doesn't work

Tags: java-me

I have installed Java ME 8.0 platform on Windows 8, Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Each time that I start device-manager (contained in bin), it appear for a second on the screen and then it ends. There is no possibility to connect devices and test apps. Someone has the same problem or know how to solve it?